# What is the Scheme equivalent of this alias code written in CL?

Tags: scheme, common-lisp

I'm trying to write the Scheme equivalent of this CL code:

```
(defmacro alias (new-name prev-name)
  `(defmacro ,new-name (&rest args)
     `(,',prev-name ,@args)))

;; Sample use:
(alias co concatenate)
```

My aim is to be able to use shorthand names for symbol and function names like:

```
(alias sa string-append)
(sa "ok" "not ok")
```

To do that I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
(define-syntax alias (new-name prev-name)
   `(define-syntax ,new-name (#!rest args)
     `(,',prev-name ,@args)))
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Well, the _Common Lisp_ equivalent would be to use symbol macros (see `define-symbol-macro` and `symbol-macrolet`).

Comment: How would you write an alias functionality using one of those macros?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with a `syntax-rules` macro that defines another `syntax-rules` macro:

```
(define-syntax alias
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ new-name prev-name)
     (define-syntax new-name
       (... (syntax-rules ()
              ((_ arg ...)
               (prev-name arg ...))))))))
```

The trickiest thing is this macro is the use of `...` to escape nested uses of `...`.

However, this is not necessarily the best way to do this. The best way probably depends on your precise Scheme implementation, as Scheme is less a language and more a family of languages. Writing portable Scheme is usually not very useful.

Comment: thank you for the answer. when I tried it on my chicken scheme it gave this error: Error: during expansion of (syntax-rules ...) - too many ellipses: (arg ...) Could you help on this ? Btw, while there are dozens of quality books and websites on CL, there are only a handful of Scheme books all of which are not so much useful and very few websites & tutorials and that limits my learning experience.

Comment: @Romario It sounds like Chicken isn’t compliant with R7RS in that respect, then—R7RS requires that `...` be allowed as an escape. I’d consider that a bug in Chicken, but your question didn’t actually specify which version of Scheme (R5RS/R6RS/R7RS) or implementation you wanted an answer for. To answer your other question, though, I’d ditch trying to write portable Scheme and just write [Racket](http://racket-lang.org), a capable, well-documented Scheme descendant. You can use Scheme implementations, too, of course, but I’d treat them more like separate languages.

Comment: @Romario It looks like Chicken Scheme does not enable R7RS compliance by default, but this answer will work if you turn it on. The difference is documented [here](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/r7rs#macros).

Comment: After I applied the R7RS extension library ("egg"), it worked out great! Now the alias functionality works flawlessly. More importantly it's been a nice piece of code to learn some gory details of Scheme. Btw, my version of Chicken Scheme was the latest 4.13.0. I just wouldn't guess the version would matter for that particular problem :)

Comment: If you want a scheme tutorial, although aimed at R6RS, https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/ is great as a learning resource.  Also https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Hello-Scheme_0021.html and the rest of the guile manual is a good resource.

Answer (score 2):

If your scheme supports R6RS syntax-case and cognates (say, guile or chez scheme), identifier-syntax is the most direct way of implementing what you want:

```
(define-syntax new-name (identifier-syntax old-name))
```

Thus:

```
(define-syntax new-display (identifier-syntax display))
(new-display "hello\n")
```

**Edit**:  I see you are using chicken.  In that case you can use er-macro-transformer to reproduce your defmacro solution (this works with chicken-4.10.0 at any rate):

```
(define-syntax alias
  (er-macro-transformer
   (lambda (exp r c)
     (let ([new-name (cadr exp)]
           [old-name (caddr exp)])
       `(define-syntax ,new-name
          (ir-macro-transformer
           (lambda (exp i c)
             `(,',old-name ,@(cdr exp)))))))))
```

Comment: This version of alias looks way more similar to the CL code.  The er-macro-transformer has made this possible. I've tried this on my Chicken Scheme-4.13.0 and it worked. So it's a nice solution. Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget that because there is only one namespace in scheme you can, and often would, just do '(define new-name old-name)' at the expense of another symbol.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, in Common Lisp you can make an alias a real function, not a macro, by settings `symbol-function` of a symbol denoting an alias like this:

```
CL-USER> (defun foo (name)
           (format nil "Hello ~A!~%" name))
FOO
CL-USER> (setf (symbol-function 'bar)
               #'foo)
#<INTERPRETED-FUNCTION FOO>
CL-USER> (bar "Bob")
"Hello Bob!
"
```